# Data in db is in wrong encoding (using CKeditor) and greek

Tags: mysql, database, encoding

I am using ckeditor 3.4 to insert data (text) to database and then display it on a page.

Problem: when I write (greek )in the ckeditor everything is fine. When I press the HTML button of the ckeditor again everything is fine (e.g. i see the actuall text typed not html entities). However when I save the data (and hence store them to the db) the stored data in the db are like this

```
"<p style="text-align: center;">
    ... ÏƒÏÎ½Ï„Î¿Î¼Î± Ï€ÎµÏÎ¹ÏƒÏƒÏŒÏ„ÎµÏÎµÏ‚ Ï€Î»Î·ÏÎ¿Ï†Î¿ÏÎ¯ÎµÏ‚...</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>"
```

Note: when I recall the data the are correctly displayed on the web page.

Actions taken so far:

1- the connection file to the db has the following: `$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

2- In the config.js of the ckeditor I have added the following lines

```
config.entities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.entities_processNumerical = false;
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'el';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};
```

3- my webpages are set to: `content="text/html;charset=utf-8"`

4- db colation: `utf8_unicode_ci / type MyIsam`

I've been searching around but no luck. 
I'd appreciate any help

Comment: what program/script are you using to view DB contents? Maybe it simply doesn't support UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers.
Solution was much simpler.
The right writing is `SET NAMES UTF8` instead of `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP or any other language that doesn't do this automatically, you need to invoke

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8'
```

on the connection before calling any statements, in order to use UTF-8 in your database.

Also make sure you are serving all pages as UTF-8 so that posted data is in UTF-8.

There are also some configuration parameters that controls how the data is sent and processed by the server, but I have never managed to get it to work without this statement.

se more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

EDIT: Ah, sorry, didn't see that you actually did this. If it is displayed correctly when you output it and your charset is set to UTF-8 on the page, then I'm assuming that you only view it in the DB with a tool that doesn't support UTF-8, or isn't configured for it? So what exactly is the problem right now?

Comment: Yes, "ÏƒÏÎ½Ï„Î¿" is like viewing utf-8 data with a viewer set on latin-1 encoding. So maybe it's just your db viewer.